# Finding differential equation from the solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $y=ax^2+bx+c$ is a general solution of a differential equation. Find the differential equation.
My attempt:

$y'= 2ax +b\\y" = 2a$

then the required form is $y"+2xy'-2y = 2a-bx+c$
But I am not sure about this. Appreciate any tips.

Comment: You could form a whole heap of differential equations from your general solution..

Comment: What do you mean? Please show me more.

Comment: The DE $y' = 2ax + b$ satisfies the general solution.. So does $y'' = 2a$. So does $y''' = 0$..

Comment: This is also a possible equation : $$xy' - y - ax^2 + c =0 $$. Your imagination is the limit ;)

Comment: You mean I can have more than 1 equation? But in the next question, I am given if y"(0) = 2A, y'(0) = B and y(0) = C for the differential equation in part a), find a, b, c. Does it mean my differential equation must have order 2?

Comment: @user73195 the answer for the second part doesn't depend on the differential equation you invent.

Comment: The answer is $y''=0$ because he is told the given family of functions is the "general solution". That means $y=Ax^2+Bx+C$ is not just a solution for token $A,B,C$, but, also includes all possible solutions to the mystery ODE.

Comment: Note $y'=2ax+b$ is not a single ODE, but, a parametrized family. Admittedly, these are semantic distinctions I raise here.